# Is there an official mega list of compatible modules?

Tags: hardware, compatibility

I'm interested in Raspberry Pi and I wonder what hardware modules are compatible with it.

How does compatibility work? Do people design parts that work with the Raspberry Pi? Or is it like an electronics thing where anything with pins will work easily?

Is there some official list of all the compatible modules? Or would such a list be too big and constantly expanding?

Comment: Hello. I have taken the liberty to remove the <modules> tag which does not seem to apply to your questions.

Comment: ask `is the RPi compatible with xyz module?`

Comment: Are you talking about hardware or software?

Comment: @Dougie hardware

Comment: There's no official list. But https://pinout.xyz/boards has details of lots of HATs and pHATs